# Is $f(t)=t^\alpha$ for $\alpha\in(0,1)$ a sub-additive function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does $|x|^p$ with $0&lt;p&lt;1$ satisfy the triangular inequality on $\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134714/does-xp-with-0p1-satisfy-the-triangular-inequality-on-mathbbr)

Is the function

$$f(t)= t^{\alpha},\quad \alpha\in (0,1)$$

a  subadditive function?

My teacher said categorically that this is true. But I'm not so sure.

EDIT: $~~~~~0\leq t\leq 1$

Comment: Try with $0\le t\le 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By homogeneity, in the inequality $(x+y)^{\alpha}\leq x^{\alpha}+y^{\alpha}$ just deal with the case $y=1$. Let $f(t):=t^{\alpha}+1-(t+1)^{\alpha}$. The derivative has the sign of $t^{\alpha-1}-(t+1)^{\alpha-1}$ which is non-negative since $\alpha<1$. Hence $f(t)\geq f(0)=0$ and we are done.

Comment: The notation $a^\alpha$ is a bit confusing, you should consider using $x,y$ or $u,v$ instead methinks.

Comment: That's true. Thanks!