# Is $u:B_1(0)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \beta$-Hölder continuous given by $u(x) =|x|^\beta $?

Tags: real-analysis, holder-spaces

Is Is $u:B_1(0)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \beta$-Hölder continuous given by $u(x) =|x|^\beta $?
i.e
\begin{equation}
\sup \left \{ \dfrac{||x|^\beta-|y|^{\beta}|}{|x-y|^{\beta}} : \begin{matrix}|x|<1 \\ |y|<1 \end{matrix}\right \} \le C <\infty
\end{equation}
Assume $0< \beta <1$.

Comment: Do you really think that it was necessary to create a new tag [tag:regularity] for this question? And if you think that this tag would be useful, you should add description of the tag in the tag-wiki and tag-excerpt; since the word [regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularity) is used in many different meanings in mathematics. (I don't think that such tag is needed.)

Comment: If you don't know what did is talking about in his comment, you can read more here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) and [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers).

Comment: @Martin: I agree. Re-tagged as holder-spaces. (Sorry, but tags don't support umlauts...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we know that $|a+b|^\beta\le |a|^\beta + |b|^\beta$ (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134714/does-xp-with-0p1-satisfy-the-triangular-inequality-on-mathbbr)), we get for $a=x-y$, $b=y$
$$|x|^\beta \le |x-y|^\beta + |y|^\beta$$
which is equivalent to
$$|x|^\beta - |y|^\beta \le |x-y|^\beta.$$
By symmetry we also have $|y|^\beta - |x|^\beta \le |x-y|^\beta$, which together gives
$$||x|^\beta - |y|^\beta| \le |x-y|^\beta.$$

This is basically the same trick as in the proof of [this form of triangle inequality](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Backwards_Form_of_Triangle_Inequality).