# Difference of powers inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Is there any inequality involving difference of powers?  I want to estimate say $x^p - y^p$, or $|x^p -y^p|$ hopefully in terms of $|x-y|^p$

Edit : $0 < p <\infty$, and I'm sure that there will be cases depending on $p$

Comment: is $p$ integer and positive ?

Comment: Surely not in terms of $x^p-y^p$ only, since for $x=y+1$, $x^2-y^2$ is big when $x$ is big.

Comment: Maybe something like $|x^p-y^p|\ge p|x-y|^{p-1}$ ($x,y>0$)?

Comment: You can create one, if you know your bounds well and prove. Otherwise, the closest I know is, minkowski inequality, $\|f\|_p+\|g\|_p\ge\|f+g\|_p$. You can see Hagen Von Eitzen's comment though.

Comment: the minkowski inequality needs $p>1$ doesn't it ?

Comment: yes, sorry, missed details.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Won't we need $x,y>1$ for your inequality? Otherwise take $p=2$, $x=10^{-4}$, $y=10^{-5}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Something like that would be ideal... Is there a proof?

Comment: This is like what I wanted http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165520/is-ub-10-rightarrow-mathbbr-beta-holder-continuous-given-by-ux-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, we have the following inequalities:

1. If $x,y>0$, then $|x-y|^p\le p|x-y|(x^{p-1}+y^{p-1}), \text{ for }p\ge 1$,
2. If $x\ge y>0$, then $|x-y|^p\le \frac{p}{2}x^{p-2}|x-y|(x^2+y^2), \text{ for }p\ge 2$.
3. (Mazur Inequality) For any real $x,y$, then $2^{1-p}|x-y|^p\le\big|x|x|^{p-1}-y|y|^{p-1}\big|\le|x-y|(|x|^{p-1}+|y|^{p-1}), \text{ for }p\ge 1$.

Comment: Can you point me towards book/paper where Mazur Inequality is discussed. I googled it myself, but couldn't find any comprehensive explanation (especially for real number case).

Comment: (3) is missing a $p$ on the right side, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

$$|x^p-y^p|=|x-y||x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}y+\cdots+xy^{p-2}+y^{p-1}|$$
If $|x|<M$, $y<M$ this gives us
$$|x^p-y^p|<pM^{p-1}|x-y|$$

Comment: $p$ is not necessarily an integer.