# Reference for "Mazur's inequality"

Tags: inequality, reference-request, absolute-value

I was looking for some specific inequalities concerning the absolute value, and I found this particular inequality in a question in this forum: [Difference of powers inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327242/difference-of-powers-inequality)

The inequality is the following:
$$
2^{1-p}|x-y|^p\le\big|x|x|^{p-1}-y|y|^{p-1}\big|\le|x-y|(|x|^{p-1}+|y|^{p-1}), \text{ for }p\ge 1
$$
and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

The user who posted this inequality as an answer named it "Mazur's inequality", but I was not able to find some references with that name on google. Are some of you familiar with this inequality? Can you provide a good reference/proof?

Comment: I found Mazur's inequality (as you stated here) in a Chinese book without references. Also, in a blog entry, the Mazur's inequality is collected without references as well.

Comment: Also, perhaps related: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0898122180900383?ref=pdf_download&fr=RR-2&rr=76e624b28a93faf8

Comment: Thank you! Could you share the link or name for the Chinese book?

Comment: https://www.zhihu.com/question/474094278/answer/2015826434

Comment: The book: Page 135, (3rd Ed.) https://www.doc88.com/p-096371580918.html

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.