# Prove $(|x| + |y|)^p \le |x|^p + |y|^p$ for $x,y \in \mathbb R$ and $p \in (0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Prove $(|x| + |y|)^p \le |x|^p + |y|^p$ for $x,y \in \mathbb R$ and $p \in (0,1]$.

A hint is given that for $0 \le \alpha \le \beta$ there exist a number $\xi \in (\beta, \alpha + \beta)$ s.t. $$(\alpha + \beta)^p - \beta^p = p \xi^{p-1}\alpha \le \alpha^{p}$$.

I see that by proving the above hint the result holds for positive numbers.

In order to prove the above hint I've considered the Intermediate value theorem, however I've not yet succeeded.

Comment: There are no negative cases, we are using absolute values.

Comment: Ahh yes, I see.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134714/does-xp-with-0p1-satisfy-the-triangle-inequality-on-mathbbr

Answer (score 6):

We want to show 
$$1\le \left(\frac{|x|}{|x|+|y|}\right)^p+\left(\frac{|y|}{|x|+|y|}\right)^p,$$
or 
$$1\le a^p+b^p\tag{1}$$
for $a,b\in [0,1]$, $a+b=1$, and $0< p\le1$. But (1) is clear since 
$$a\le a^p,b\le b^p.$$

Answer (score 4):

We want to show that for non-negative $s$ and $t$ we have $(s+t)^p\le s^p+t^p$.
Fix $s$, and let 
$$f(t)=s^p+t^p-(s+t)^p.$$
Note that $f(0)=0$. For $t\gt 0$ we have $f'(t)=p(t^{p-1}-(s+t)^{p-1})\ge 0$, so $f$ is non-decreasing.