# How to show $L^a-l^a \ge (L-l)^a$?

Tags: inequality

Is it possible to show that $L^a-l^a \ge (L-l)^a$ (or the opposite), where $l \in [0,L]$  and $0<a<1$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134714/does-xp-with-0p1-satisfy-the-triangular-inequality-on-mathbbr) seems to be related:  (And maybe also other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/134714).)

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

With $\lambda = l/L \in [0, 1], \qquad (1-\lambda)^a \geqslant 1-\lambda^a $ is true, as $f(\lambda) = (1-\lambda)^a + \lambda^a$ is concave for $a \in (0, 1)$ and hence its minima have to be when $\lambda$ takes extreme values in the interval.