# Show that $f(x) = x^{{1}/{3}}$ is Hölder on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am trying to show that $f(x) = x^{{1}/{3}}$ is Hölder continous on $\mathbb{R}$, but I have not been able to make much progress.

To show that this is indeed true we would need to show that

$$\left|x^{1/3}-y^{1/3}\right| \leq C|x-y|^\alpha.$$
I think $C = 1$ and $\alpha = 1/3$, but I can't seen to make the inequalities work.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean $[0,\infty)$ instead of $\mathbb R$ since $x\mapsto x^{\frac13}$ is not real-valued for negative $x$.

Comment: Yes, sorry -- you are right.

Comment: @Math1000: What do you mean? The function $x\mapsto x^{3}$ is bijective (look at the graph), so why isn't $x\mapsto x^{1/3}$ just the inverse?

Comment: @WillR How do you define $(-1)^{1/3}$? It is true that $(-1)^3 = 1$, but also true that $$\left(e^{2\pi i/3}\right)^3=\left(e^{4\pi i/3}\right)^3=1.$$

Comment: @Math1000: $(-1)^{3}=-1$, not $1$. While there are non-real numbers that give $-1$ as their cube, that doesn't change the fact that $-1$ is a perfectly valid real cube root for $-1.$ Similarly, $-(a^{1/3})$ is a perfectly valid real cube root for $-a$ whenever $a\geq0$ is real.

Comment: Whoops, typo. Anyway, I suppose it is a moot point - the phrasing "Hölder continous on $\mathbb R$" would imply that the function $f$ is defined for real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a direct proof. For $x=0$ or $y=0$, the inequality holds obviously so assume $x,y \in (0, \infty)$ and without loss of generality $x \geq y$. Now the inequality holds for $x$ and $y$ if and only if 
$$(\sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[3]{y})^3 \leq x-y.$$
Expanding the left hand side gives the inequality holds if and only if 
$$\sqrt[3]{xy^2} - \sqrt[3]{x^2y} \leq 0.$$
This is true if and only if $$xy^2 \leq x^2y$$ which is equivalent to $x \geq y$, which is true by assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Take $0<p<1$ and use $|u+v|^p\leq |u|^p+|v|^p$ (look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134714/does-xp-with-0p1-satisfy-the-triangle-inequality-on-mathbbr)). By letting $u=x-y$, $v=y$, you find that $|x|^p-|y|^p\leq |x-y|^p$. By symmetry you get the other part.