# How can I prove that $(a+b)^{1/p} > a^{1/p} +b^{1/p}$ for every $0< p< 1.$ and for every $a,b > 0.$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, proof-explanation

How can I prove that $(a+b)^{1/p} > a^{1/p} +b^{1/p}$ for every $0< p< 1.$ and for every $a,b > 0.$

I can see this proof on this site [Does $|x|^p$ with $0<p<1$ satisfy the triangle inequality on $\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134714/does-xp-with-0p1-satisfy-the-triangle-inequality-on-mathbbr?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I do not understand how this will help me in my proof? could anyone give me a simple proof for my question.(because I do not quite understand the proof given in the above link.)

Comment: Adapt the proof of the accepted answer, i.e., construct functions, take the derivative to get the monotonicity of the function, hence an inequality of the function, and go back to your inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $1/p>1$ and if we ler $r=1/p>1$ you are to prove $(a+b)^{r}>a^{r}+b^{r}$ for $a,b>0$. If suffices to prove $(1+x)^{r}>1+x^{r}$ for $x>0$, for you may substitute $x=b/a$.

Let $\varphi(x)=(1+x)^{r}-(1+x^{r})$ for $x>0$, then $\varphi(0)=0$ and $\varphi'(x)=r(1+x)^{r-1}-rx^{r-1}=r((1+x)^{r-1}-x^{r-1})>0$, as $1+x>x$, $(1+x)^{r-1}>x^{r-1}$.

So $\varphi$ is strictly increasing, this means that $\varphi(x)>\varphi(0)$, so $(1+x)^{r}-(1+x^{r})>0$ and hence $(1+x)^{r}>1+x^{r}$.

Comment: Why we need to be sure that $\phi (0) = 0$

Comment: Or else what can you say about $\varphi(x)>\varphi(0)$? Remember we want $(1+x)^{r}-(1+x^{r})>0$, if $\varphi(0)$ is not zero, we cannot conclude anything.

Comment: Sorry it is clear for me now I just did not complete reading until the end

Comment: Perfectly done :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

Consider two functions: $f(x)=(a+x)^{\frac{1}{p}}-a^{\frac{1}{p}}$ and $g(x)=x^{\frac{1}{p}}$. Notice, that $f(0)=g(0)=0$ and for every $x \geq 0$ $f'(x) > g'(x)$, because:

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{p}(a+x)^{\frac{1}{p}-1}=\frac{1}{p}(a+x)^{\frac{1-p}{p}} > \frac{1}{p}(x)^{\frac{1-p}{p}} = g'(x)$$

This holds, because $1-p>0$ and $a>0$.

Concluding, $f(x)>g(x)$ for every $x>0$, which proves the inequality after substitution $x=b$.

Comment: Why if the derivatives are greater than each other then the original functions are greater than each other in the same way.

Comment: Because they gain more and $f(0)=g(0)$