# Sum of real powers: $\sum_{i=1}^{N}{x_i^{\beta}} \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}{x_i}\right)^{\beta}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, convex-analysis

Let $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ be positive real numbers and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$.
Can we say that:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{N}{x_i^{\beta}} \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}{x_i}\right)^{\beta}$$

I know that this holds if $\beta \in \mathbb{N}$. Does the above inequality have a name in case it's true?

Comment: Have you tried this with any actual numbers?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't tried.

Comment: @kagami Try taking $N=100$, all $x_i=0.01$, and $\beta=\frac{1}{2}$. The LHS is 10. The RHS is 1. As a result of that (+ umpteen similar examples) and the fact that you admitted to making zero effort to see if your inequality was true, you now (0516Z) have 4 out of the necessary 5 close votes.

Comment: @almagest some of the answers correct that. The inequality is reversed for $\beta<1$.

Comment: @AD. Sure, but that will not be enough to stop closure. The question needs editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case $0<\beta<1$ we have re reversed inequality
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\right)^\beta\leq \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^\beta$$
Also, this can actually be used to prove the inequality of the present post. 
[Here are some details](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4094/how-do-you-show-that-l-p-subset-l-q-for-p-leq-q/4122#4122) (for the case $\beta>1$ choose $p=1$ and $q=\beta$).

Comment: do you happen to know the name of the inequality in the general case with $p \leq q$?

Comment: I've followed the proof but I would be grateful if you refer me to the reference from which you have inequality (1)

Comment: @kagami No, I have never seen a name for it. We could call it the embedding inequality of $\ell^p$ into $\ell^q$ for $p<q$.

Comment: @kagami If I remember correctly it is an exercise in Zelazko's book [Banach Algebras](https://books.google.se/books?id=LwKrAAAAIAAJ&q=zelazko+sequence+l-p&dq=zelazko+sequence+l-p&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkhMaE38bNAhVH_iwKHZquAW4Q6AEINjAA).

Answer (score 6):

Note that this amounts to showing that 
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}{x_i}^{\beta}\right)^{1/\beta} \leq \sum_{i=1}^N
 x_i
$$
This fact holds for all $\beta \geq 1$, and it is an instance of the [Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Comment: How can we see that this is an instance of Minkowski inequality.?

Comment: Let 
$$
v_i = (\overbrace{0,\dots,0}^{i-1},x_i,0,\dots,0)
$$
and note that 
$$
\left\| \sum_i v_i \right\|_{\beta} \leq \sum_i \|v_i\|_{\beta}
$$

Answer (score 3):

If $\beta \ge 1$, this is a consequence of [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) applied to the convex function $t \mapsto t^{\beta}$.

If $\beta < 1$, this is false with $x_i = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $0<\beta<1$, then the opposite inequality is true, since the function $x\mapsto x^\beta$ is [subadditive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity) in this case. See [Prove variant of triangle inequality containing p-th power for 0 < p < 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80003/prove-variant-of-triangle-inequality-containing-p-th-power-for-0-p-1) and [An inequality concerning concave functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164177/an-inequality-concerning-concave-functions).
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}{x_i}\right)^{\beta} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{N}{x_i^{\beta}}.$$

For $\beta=1$ then there is equality
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}{x_i^{\beta}} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}{x_i}\right)^{\beta}.$$

If $\beta>1$, then $x\mapsto x^\beta$ is superadditive and thus.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}{x_i^{\beta}} \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}{x_i}\right)^{\beta}.$$

In general, concave function $f(x)$ with $f(0)=0$ is subadditive and concave function $f(x)$ with $f(0)=0$ is superadditive. The proof can be found, for example, in:

- The Wikipedia article on [subadditivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity)
- This answer: [Prove variant of triangle inequality containing p-th power for 0 < p < 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80003/prove-variant-of-triangle-inequality-containing-p-th-power-for-0-p-1/80015#80015)

See also Exercise 16.6.4, [p.480](http://books.google.com/books?id=rqqvbKOC4c8C&pg=PA480), in M. Kuczma: An introduction to the theory of functional equations and inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

The best part about the inequality $$\sum_{n = 1}^{N}x_{i}^{\beta} \leq \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{N}x_{i}\right)^{\beta}\tag{1}$$ is that it is homogeneous in variables $x_{i}$ and hence we can assume without any loss of generality that $\sum x_{i} = 1$. Since each each $x_{i}$ is positive and they sum to $1$ it follows that each $x_{i}$ lies between $0$ and $1$ and hence $x_{i}^{\beta} < x_{i}$ if $\beta > 1$ and therefore $$\sum x_{i}^{\beta} < \sum x_{i} = 1 = 1^{\beta} = \left(\sum x_{i}\right)^{\beta}$$ If $0 < \beta < 1$ or $\beta < 0$ then we have $x_{i}^{\beta} > x_{i}$ and hence the inequality is reversed.